# How to resolve AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next' in python?

Tags: python, linked-list

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
class Solution:
    def insertionSortList(self, head):
        head=[1]
        dummy = ListNode()
        curr = head
        
        while curr:
            # At each iteration, we insert an element into the resulting list.
            prev = dummy
            
            # find the position to insert the current node
            while prev.next and prev.next.val < curr.val:
                prev = prev.next
                
            next = curr.next
            # insert the current node to the new list
            curr.next = prev.next
            prev.next = curr
            
            # moving on to the next iteration
            curr = next
            
        return dummy.next
    
test = [-1, 5, 3, 4, 0]
head = ListNode(test)
res_head = Solution().insertionSortList(head)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Untitled.py", line 31, in
>
> res_head = Solution().insertionSortList(head)   File "Untitled.py", line 19, in insertionSortList
> next = curr.next AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: You set head to `[1]` but it should be a `ListNode`.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're overwriting `head` with list `[1]`, which would cause this error.

```py
def insertionSortList(self, head):
    head=[1] # Head is being set to type list here
```

Comment: Specifically, how should I change? Could you post the entire code?

Comment: @chierhu, it looks like `head` is supposed to be type ListNode. I'd remove `head=[1]` entirely to prevent the overwrite.